# Desktop Intelligence - Lookup Query

Tags: mysql, sql-server, t-sql, business-intelligence, business-objects

In Desktop Intelligence, When I run a Query With filter condition "service Type" = 'I', I get below query output.

Thanks for your time for looking into this posting, appreciate any help.

Comment: Then what have you done so far ?

Comment: Thats my question how to?

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select a.partner from dates as a
where a.servicetype = 'i' 
and exists (select 1 from dates as b where a.partner = b.partner 
    and b.servicetype = 'p' and b.servicedate 
    between a.fromdate and a.enddate)
```

This gives me the below output -

partner

A

B

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sam
sorry if am not clear in my question.
I need to find out a partner who claimed to service type P(for any date which is between Service type 'I' dates) while he got service type I. each partner from date of service and to date of service will be different so I cant use From date and End date as fixed. the query should go to each partner from and end date of service in service type 'I' and look for service type 'P'. 
hope am clear 
any help will be appreciated

Comment: I am assuming that columns - partner,fromdate, enddate, servicetype,record and servicedate all are in one table. If you plan to have columns - Record# and ServiceDate    on the second table then just update the table name inside the where exists clause. I have updated my answer. Let me know if this helps..

Comment: Thank you so much Sam its working...and sorry for late reply.

Comment: Hi If you like the answer dont forget to rate it.This gives motivation to the person who spend his or her time in answering the question